# Instantiating Routers Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

Hi I am struggling through working with backbone routers, and I am wanting to find out about instantiating routers.

Can I have one routers file in my app where all the routes are defined, but I make an instance of the router in my appView and in my appModel. I am doing this so that I can call the router from both the view and the model, however I feel that this might be a rather sloppy way to do this?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Whats preventing you from accessing the router from view and model...? Are you working on a modular app using something like `require.js`..? Please provide more info and sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this that has worked for me in the past is to create a global javascript file that is included on every page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
window.APP          = {};
APP.Routers         = {};
</script>
```

Render the router once on page load:

```
APP.Routers['my_router_name'] = new MyRouterName({});
```

Now you can access it anyplace throughout the app by

```
APP.Routers.my_router_name
```

I tend to follow this pattern with not only routers, but also we collections, models, etc. also.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
window.APP          = {};
APP.Routers         = {};
APP.Collections     = {};
APP.Models          = {};
</script>
```

This solves the problem you have stated here it seems...."I am doing this so that I can call the router from both the view and the model".